# Помогите с написанием бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, бот

Помогите с написанием бота, пишу для школьного проекта бот-задачник по физике, необходимо что бы в функции zad(zadacha, не то о чем вы подумали)  сохранялись переменные  V и х, пока что я их сделал конкретными что бы проверить работу если переменные зафиксированны. необходимо что бы переменные сохранялись на 2 и более итерации функции.

```
import random
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('не скажу')
zadachki_iopta=['тело брошенно горизонтально с некоторой высоты с начальной скоростью V м/с. Через какое время вектор скорости будет направлен под углом 45 градусов к горизонту?','Мальчик бросил горизонтально мяч из окна, находящегося на высоте' , ' м, Сколько времени летел мяч до земли и с какой скоростью он был брошен, если он упал на расстоянии ',' метров от основания дома?', 'Как изменится время и дальность полёта тела, брошенного горизонтально с некоторой высоты, если начальную скоростью увеличить в ',' раза ?']
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    item1= types.KeyboardButton('получить_задачу')
    markup.add(item1 )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'привет', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def zad(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        x = 1
        V = 76
        var = V
        if message.text == 'получить_задачу':
            if x == 1:
                markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                item1 = types.KeyboardButton(str(var/10))
                item2 = types.KeyboardButton(str(var))
                item3 = types.KeyboardButton(str(var/5))
                item4 = types.KeyboardButton(str(var/2))
                back = types.KeyboardButton('назад')
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, zadachki_iopta[x-1])
                markup.add(item1, item4, item3, item2, back)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'V='+str(var)+' м/с',reply_markup=markup)
                V=var
        if x == 1 and message.text == str(V/10):
            print('daun')
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('получить_задачу')
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'верно)',reply_markup=markup)
        elif x == 1 and message.text == str(V):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неверно(')
        elif x == 1 and message.text == str(V / 5):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неверно(')
        elif x == 1 and message.text == str(V / 2):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'неверно(')
        elif message.text == 'назад':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('получить_задачу')
            markup.add(item1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'главное меню', reply_markup=markup)
            V=var
        print(message.text)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: сохраняйте куда-нибудь, а когда надо — извлекайте.

Comment: Запишите в файл или базу данных с пометкой - id чата и id задачи, которую решает в данный момент для данного пользователя ваш бот. На след.итерации вытаскивайте с файла или бд эти значения

Comment: в этом и проблема, я не знаю как с синтаксисом питона  нормально это сделать. я не очень понимаю как работает функция, чтобы в ней извлекать